# Freemarker: Convert date from Scientific Notation to a number

Tags: freemarker

I am a complete Freemarker newbie and I'm using a framework that uses freemarker template. I'm trying to sort a sequence of hashes based on a certain field "date".

My input json looks like below:

```
{"fields": [
                [
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "date": 1.563457325E9,
                        "id": "abc",
                        "size": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "date": 1.563426843E9,
                        "id": "def",
                        "size": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "date": 1.563454092E9,
                        "id": "ghi",
                        "size": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "date": 1.563425862E9,
                        "id": "jkl",
                        "size": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "date": 1.563426128E9,
                        "id": "mno",
                        "size": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "date": 1.563453696E9,
                        "id": "pqr",
                        "size": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "date": 1.563426813E9,
                        "id": "stu",
                        "size": 0.0
                    },
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "date": 1.563426177E9,
                        "id": "vwx",
                        "size": 0.0
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
```

When I'm trying to do this: `<#assign j=fields[0].eval>` , I am getting the below error:

> Failed to "?eval" string with this error: ---begin-message--- Syntax
>   error in ?eval-ed string in line 1, column 55: Encountered "E9", but
>   was expecting one of: ".."  "..*" "," "}" "." "[" "("
>   "?" "!"  "??" "+" "-" "*" "/" "%" "!=" "=" "=="
>   ">="  ">"   
>     ---end-message--- The failing expression: ==>
>   fields[0]?eval [in template "89-1070010335" at line 1, column 14] ----
>   FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related)

I want to do something like this:

```
<#assign j=fields[0]>
<#list j?sort_by("date") as i>
  ${i.date}: ${i.id}
</#list>
```

How can I convert the date field from scientific notation to a number in freemarker and then sort_by based on the value of this date field?

I would be glad if I can get some pointers or any particular reference from the [Freemarker documentation note](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_sort_by).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Data model contain nested lists, so we have to take nested list directives in the template also like below.

```
  <#list fields as field>
    <#list field?sort_by("date") as innerField>
      ${innerField.date?replace(",", "")} : ${innerField.id}
    </#list>
    </#list>
```

Below snippet converts the scientific notation to number.

```
<#assign scientificFormat = "1.563426177E9">
<#assign number = scientificFormat?number?replace(",", "")>
${number}
```

Source: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html

Comment: Output: 1563425862 : jkl
  1563426128 : mno
  1563426177 : vwx
  1563426813 : stu
  1563426843 : def
  1563453696 : pqr
  1563454092 : ghi
  1563457325 : abc

Comment: Please edit your answer to add all of your answer. Also, while this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.